# Fatal error C1083: Не удается открыть предкомпилированный заголовок

Tags: c++

> DebugFirst.pch: No such file or directory.

Как я понял, проге необходим файл в `Debug\First.pch`. Я его создал, но все равно не идет компилирование.

```
// First.cpp: определяет точку входа для консольного приложения. //

#include "StdAfx.h"

int main () { cout << "Hello, World!\n";
     return 0;
}
```

Скажите, как решить эту проблему. Я использую для компиляции Microsoft Visual C++ 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Создайте пустое консольное приложение (Console aplication, потом отметка Empty project).
Добавьте в Source files "First.cpp". В этот файл напишите свой код. Компилируйте.

Comment: как я понял то мне нужно создать Консольное Приложение Win32 но отметки Empty project я не вижу

Comment: после того, как Вы ввели название проекта, нажали ОК, открывается окно Win32 Application Wizard, нажимаете Next, в следующем окне в разделе Additional options - первый пункт Empty project.
Скриншот: http://i32.fastpic.ru/big/2011/1118/96/053ef9e25a8f2f528019b01aec877b96.png

Answer (score 0):

Если не пересоздавать проект, то нужно убрать #include "StdAfx.h" и в настройках проекта в разделе CC++ и отключить precompiled headers.